# Python type hinting a deque filled with myclass objects

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, type-hinting

using Python 3.6 or newer, I want to type hint a function **myfunc** that returns an object of MyClass.

How can I hint, that **myqueue** is a **deque** filled with **MyClass** objects?

```
from collections import deque

global_queue = deque()

class MyClass:
    pass

def myfunc(myqueue=global_queue) -> MyClass:
    return myqueue.popleft()

for i in range(10):
    global_queue.append(MyClass())
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Python 3.9, you can use `deque['MyClass']()` directly.

If you are using Python 3.6.1 or higher, you can use [`typing.Deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Deque):

```
from typing import Deque
from collections import deque

global_queue: Deque['MyClass'] = deque()

class MyClass:
    pass

def myfunc(myqueue: Deque[MyClass] = global_queue) -> MyClass:
    return myqueue.popleft()

for i in range(10):
    global_queue.append(MyClass())
```

Alternatively, you can do `global_queue = Deque['MyClass']()` instead -- at runtime, that'll construct a `collections.deque` object.

If you need to support Python 3.5, install the [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) 3rd party library and do `from typing_extensions import Deque`. That library contains backports of types that were added after the typing module was first added to the standard library.

Comment: There's a Deque in typing?! Hah! I'd been looking so hard when it was right under my nose. Gotta love community.